# How to print on HPlip network printer from bash

Tags: linux, bash, ghostscript

I have a network printer defined in HPLip.
Is there any possibility to print files from command line (bash) eg. using ghostscript?

My printer:

```
cups_uri: hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_P2015_Series?ip=192.168.1.3
printer-uri-supported: ipp://localhost:631/printers/HP_LaserJet_P2015
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to use CUPS? Here is a tutorial on command line printing CUPS (which is almost certainly installed on your system already, and if it is not, can be installed easily), if you are not familiar with it: http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html

Comment: Glad to hear it. I posted that as the answer so you can accept it and have this question marked as solved, in case anyone else comes along with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is CUPS. Here is a tutorial on command line printing CUPS (which is almost certainly installed on your system already, and if it is not, can be installed easily). if you are not familiar with it, here is an excellent primer: http://cups.org/documentation.php/options.html